# $X_1, ..., X_n$ are i.i.d. and $E(|X_i|)$ is finite. How to show that $(|X_1|+\cdots+|X_n|)/n$ converges to $E(|X_i|)$ in probability?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expected-value, law-of-large-numbers

$X_1, \cdots, X_n$ are i.i.d. and $E(|X_i|)$ is finite.

Show that $(|X_1|+\cdots+|X_n|)/n$ converge to $E(|X_i|)$ in probability and that $E((|X_1|+\cdots+|X_n|)/n)$ converge to $E(|X_i|)$.

I think this may need characteristic functions or law of large numbers to solve but don't know how. Can someone give some hint?

Comment: Do you know the statement of the weak law of large numbers?

Comment: Yes but the weak version holds for Xi instead of absolute value of Xi, I don't think it is that esay using weak law directly

Comment: Well, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent what can you say about $|X|$ and $|Y|$?

Comment: So I just say functions of iid R.V.s. are independent? Is that trivial or I need to do some proof?

Comment: Yes it's characteristic function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\{X_i\}$ is an i.i.d sequence of random variables, then so is $\{|X_i|\}$. Now you can apply the [weak law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law) to the sequence $\{|X_i|\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The second half seems trivial.

$$ \mathbb{E}( (|X_1| + |X_2| + \dots) /n ) = \frac{1}{n}(\mathbb{E}(|X_1|)+\mathbb{E}(|X_2|)+\dots) = \mathbb{E}(|X_1|)$$

as they are identically distributed. (We don't even need independence).

I guess this is convergence but this is just a constant sequence.

Comment: I just wonder can strictly equality imply convergence?

Comment: These things are equal. A constant sequence converges to it's value (cf real analysis). I feel like I'm missing the question.

Comment: Got it thanks !